# How to use user information storing a file

Tags: session, stored-procedures, doctrine

I made a web-application in which a registrated user can upload a file through a form.

I would like that, whit the information in the form, the data stored could be completed by the date and the information of the specific user that uploaded it.

Essentially the user is stored in the database with his information about the missions that can manage, this information should be stored in $product.

This is my controller:

```
  public function createAction(Request $request)
  {

             $product = new Product();
             $now = new \DateTime();
             $product->setUploadTime($now);        
             $product->getMission($session);            

             $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)
                 ->add('name', 'text')
                 ->add('data','textarea')            
                 ->add('save', 'submit')
                 ->getForm();                     


             $form->handleRequest($request);
             if ($form->isValid()) {

               $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
               $em->persist($product);
               $em->flush();
```

In this example the "mission" information is "null", how can I get this information?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the getMission method on a fresh instance of Product, so the informations can only be null.

The right way to obtain the mission, that is an information owned by the user in the session, is to call $product->setMission( $this->getUser()->getMission() );